# Compare two string fields with format HH:MM AM/PM in Lotusscript

Tags: time, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a dilemma. I'm trying to compare two TEXT fields, TimeDate having HH:MM AM/PM format, and TempTimeDate having HH:MM AM/PM format.

May I ask how do I compare them in Lotusscript?

Answer (score 3):

Yes but, what exactly do you mean by "compare" ? Since testing equality would be trivial, I'll assume you want to know if one date is earlier than the other.

In LotusScript, *the* way to go is to instanciate [`NotesDateTime`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_NOTESDATETIME_CLASS.html) objects,
then use their [`TimeDifference`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TIMEDIFFERENCE_METHOD.html) method.

Now, it would maybe be a good time to ask *why* are dates stored in plain text fields. One option could be to simply change their type to DateTime in the form, then run a simple agent base on [`@TextToTime`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_TEXTTOTIME.html). That way, from now on and forever, `getItemValue` would directly return a DateTime object. You'd also gain a finer control of format in documents and views and leave a generally cleaner, more consistent and more maintenable design.